# vuetify form field rules on touched fields in composition api

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

I'm using vue 3 and vuetify 3 with the composition api. I have 2 v-text-fields and a v-select and I'm running rules on all 3.  Something like:

```
<v-text-field
  ref="a"
  :rules=[checkMe(a, b, c)]
/>
<v-text-field
  ref="b"
  :rules=[checkMe(a, b, c)]
/>
<v-select
  ref="c"
  :rules=[checkMe(a,b,c)]
  :items="myItems"
>
</v-select>

<script setup>
function checkMe(a, b, c): void {
  console.log(a,b,c);
}
```

And that's working fine, I can see the console logging out a, b, and c.

The rule I want is that checkMe should return false only if c===apple, a===foobar, and b has been touched, the user has focused on b and blurred out of b.  I don't care what b's value is; it can be blank.  If the user loads the page, clicks on c and selects banana then types rum in a, there's no error.  But as soon as the user clicks on b, then blurs, an error message should appear.

Any ideas or examples?  TIA